# Performing network connection "diagnose" / "troubleshoot" via command line in Windows

Tags: windows-10, networking, command-line, powershell, netsh

Is there a way in command line to do the steps that Windows 10 does when you right click a network connection and choose "diagnose" or when you tell it to troubleshoot a connection?

I'm thinking perhaps something with the `netsh` command, but I tried searching and couldn't find anything which covered this, and some stuff required restarting the computer which the GUI options do not.

Comment: maybe item 3 in this article is what you're looking for? https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-fix-network-internet-connection-problems-in-windows. I just came across it myself today.

Answer (score 0):

The following are common Microsoft Windows network commands:

**Ipconfig**

Displays all current TCP/IP network configuration values and refreshes Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (DHCP) and Domain Name System (DNS) settings. Used without parameters, ipconfig displays Internet Protocol version 4 (IPv4) and IPv6 addresses, subnet mask, and default gateway for all adapters
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ipconfig

**Ping**
Helps in determining TCP/IP Networks IP address as well as determine issues with the network and assists in resolving them.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ping

**Netstat**

Displays active TCP connections, ports on which the computer is listening, Ethernet statistics, the IP routing table, IPv4 statistics (for the IP, ICMP, TCP, and UDP protocols), and IPv6 statistics (for the IPv6, ICMPv6, TCP over IPv6, and UDP over IPv6 protocols).Used without parameters, this command displays active TCP connections.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/netstat

**Netsh**

Netsh is a command-line scripting utility that allows you to display or modify the network configuration of a computer that is currently running. Netsh commands can be run by typing commands at the netsh prompt and they can be used in batch files or scripts. Remote computers and the local computer can be configured by using netsh commands.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/netsh/netsh-contexts

**Tracert**
The tracert command is used to visually see a network packet being sent and received and the amount of hops required for that packet to get to its destination
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/314868/how-to-use-tracert-to-troubleshoot-tcp-ip-problems-in-windows

**Telnet**
Telnet is software that allows users to remotely access another computer such as a server, network device, or other computer. With telnet users can connect to a device or computer, manage a network device, setup a device, transfer files, etc.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/telnet